# Create Query Definition with Ampscript - incomplete instructions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query

Marketing Cloud developer documentation is patchy at best, and I'm trying to create and execute a query definition using Ampscript. I have got so far:

```
%%[
VAR @q, @qdf, @qn, @qdf_Key
SET @qn = 'Population Query'
SET @q = CreateObject('Query')
SET @qdf = CreateObject('QueryDefinition')
SET @qdf_Key = @qn
SetObjectProperty(@qdf, 'CategoryID', '0')
/*SetObjectProperty(@qdf, 'DataExtensionTarget', 'TCA_99919_APP_LOL_X1')*/
SetObjectProperty(@qdf, 'Description', 'PLEASE DO NOT TOUCH')
SetObjectProperty(@qdf, 'Name', @qn)
SetObjectProperty(@qdf, 'QueryText', 'SELECT * FROM Media_Master')
SetObjectProperty(@qdf, 'TargetType', 'DataExtension')
SetObjectProperty(@qdf, 'TargetUpdateType', 'Overwrite')

]%%
Query Name: %%=v(@qn)=%%<br>
Query Definition Key: %%=v(@qdf_Key)=%%<br>
```

I could not get the SetObjectProperty 'DataExtensionTarget' to work and am therefore unsure how to set the target data extension. Can anyone help? What else do I need to do? All this renders fine on a microsite I'm testing it on.

Comment: Can you use SSJS do this?